# macaulay 2 for algebraic and geometric methods in statistics

Tags: macaulay2

> Consider the vector *h* = (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2) and the matrix *A* =
> 2 0 0 1 1 0
> 0 2 0 1 0 1
> 0 0 2 0 1 1
>
> 1. write code in Macaulay 2 version 1.21 to Compute generators for the toric ideals IA and IA,h.
> 2. What familiar statistical model is the discrete exponential family MA,h ?

unable to get IA,h!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Quasidegrees package](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Quasidegrees/html/index.html) to generate toric ideals.

```
Macaulay2, version 1.21
with packages: ConwayPolynomials, Elimination, IntegralClosure, InverseSystems, Isomorphism, LLLBases,
               MinimalPrimes, OnlineLookup, PrimaryDecomposition, ReesAlgebra, Saturation, TangentCone

i1 : loadPackage "Quasidegrees"
o1 = Quasidegrees
o1 : Package

i2 : h = vector {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}
o2 = | 1 |
     | 1 |
     | 1 |
     | 2 |
     | 2 |
     | 2 |

       6
o2 : ZZ

i3 : A = matrix {{2,0,0,1,1,0},{0,2,0,1,0,1},{0,0,2,0,1,1}}
o3 = | 2 0 0 1 1 0 |
     | 0 2 0 1 0 1 |
     | 0 0 2 0 1 1 |

              3        6
o3 : Matrix ZZ  <--- ZZ

i4 : R = QQ[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6]
o4 = R
o4 : PolynomialRing

i5 : IA = toricIdeal(A, R)
                                                           2          2          2
o5 = ideal (x x  - x x , x x  - x x , x x  - x x , x x  - x , x x  - x , x x  - x )
             4 5    1 6   2 5    4 6   3 4    5 6   2 3    6   1 3    5   1 2    4
o5 : Ideal of R
```

For the second part, look at the [Algebraic Optimization Degree package](https://github.com/Macaulay2/Workshop-2020-Cleveland/tree/ISSAC-AlgOpt/alg-stat/AlgebraicOptimization), maybe it will work for you or get an idea from it. For example with the toricMLIdeal function, you can [compute the toric Maximum likelihood ideal](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3427218.3427222).